# Everpad not syncing - Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, sync, everpad

I have installed everpad (nvbn-rm 2.5.6-0~saucy) but cannot sync with an existing an evernote account. I have also tried creating a new account on evernote however create/sync notes do not work. I have logged out and back in but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Tested Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Try to stop everpad-provider with `killall everpad-provider`
, run it from terminal with `everpad-provider --verbose`, then try to sync. What is your terminal output?

Output is  Segmentation fault?

This should fix your segfault:
Open file `/usr/share/pyshared/everpad/provider/daemon.py` file in editor with sudo and near the file end after line `dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)` add the following line:
`dbus.mainloop.glib.threads_init()`
Be careful with the indentation. You should get something like this:

```
...
    try:
        fcntl.lockf(fp, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
        dbus.mainloop.glib.threads_init()
        app = ProviderApp(args.verbose, sys.argv)
        app.exec_()
    except IOError:
...
```

After changes try run everpad-provider again.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is reported here. https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/issues/369?source=cc

I think it is fixed now (except for everpad-lens which still doesn't work). Update latest version for saucy from ppa.